# How do I sum variable parts of a row in Excel?

Tags: excel

I'm looking for a way to sum up the 4 best scores out of these 6 tournaments played by these 2 players. Is there a code to place in J2/J3 that will automatically pick the best 4 scores and sum them, ignoring the 2 worst scores? Thanks in advance!

[See this picture for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J058i.png)

[Still getting an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnObB.png)

Comment: Thanks all for the answers, but I must be doing something wrong? Using CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER when the cell is filled with the code. See 2nd pic in OP for reference.

Comment: As Axel Richter pointed out in his comment, using the array literal syntax `{1;2;3;4}` removes the need to use Ctrl-Shift-Enter. Just enter that line normally on the top row for which you want to sum the top four values, and drag it down into any additional rows.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still getting an error. Included a pic in the OP.

Comment: @Praedyn: If you have a Dutch Excel version, then you must use Dutch formula notation. Maybe `{=SOM(GROOTSTE(D2:I2;RIJ($1:$4)))}` or `=SOM(GROOTSTE(D2:I2;{1;2;3;4}))`. Note the Dutch names and semicolon as the list separator and arguments separator.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an array formula.

`=SUM(LARGE(D2:I2, ROW($1:$4)))`, entered with Ctrl-Shift-Enter

Explanation: `ROW($1:$4)` expands to the array `{1;2;3;4}`, which is used by the `LARGE` function to take the first, second, third and fourth highest values in the given range.

Alternatively, you can specify this using an array literal to remove the need for Ctrl-Shift-Enter: `=SUM(LARGE(d2:i2, {1;2;3;4}))`

Comment: Your method of generating the array constant "`ROW(1:4)`" is not stable, and will change to non-useful values as you drag the formula down.

Comment: Using a array literal `{1,2,3,4}` or `{1;2;3;4}` will avoid the need of CSE.
`=SUM(LARGE(D2:I2,{1;2;3;4}))`

Comment: An explanation of how this works would increase the value of the answer.